# Piecewise function is my solution correct?

Tags: calculus

A bookshop sells the first 5 books for 50 pound per book, the next 5 books for 30 pound per book and the following for 15 pound per book.
I want to write a function for $f§. Is the following function correct?

\begin{equation}
f(x) = 
\left\{
    \begin{array}{lr}
        50x, & \text{if } 0 \le x\le 5\\
        30x+100, & \text{if } 5 \leq x\leq 10\\
15x+250, & \text{if }  x\geq 10
    \end{array}
\right\} 
\end{equation}

Comment: Looks good.  Might help to include the intermediate steps...for $5≤x≤10$, for example, the answer is $30(x-5)+250=30x-150+250=30x+100$.  Just to make it clear where your terms are coming from.

Comment: The coefficients of $x$ look correct.  So if you check the first two expressions when $x=5$ and the last two when $x=10$ then you can confirm your results

Comment: But why is the function not just 50x, 30x and 15x? Why do we need 100 and 250?

Comment: I don't understand...I thought you designed this function, no?  You call it "my solution" after all.   In any case, the $30$ per unit (say) only applies to the units *after* the first $5$ are sold. Work it out carefully for the case of, say, $7$ units sold.